# Meteor error “Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html”

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, meteor, mime-types

I am using Meteor (quite new using this framework) and I'm getting the following warning in Chrome whenever I try to load a page with an id as parameter:

The url is something like this: http://localhost:3000/post/UUID
And this is the warning output:

> UUID:114 Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:3000/postDetail/style.css"

I'm kind of lost right now. What should I do about it?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: The path to `style.css` is wrong. You've got a relative path to `style.css` somewhere. Change it to an absolute path.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem.

Thanks!